# Access SurfaceWindow from TagVisualization

Tags: wpf, pixelsense

I'm looking for an easy way to access my main SurfaceWindow from a TagVisualization that I have. The scenario is that I want to pass along data from my TagVisualization back to the SurfaceWindow. Is there an easy way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

TagVisualization inherits from FrameworkElement, so a Parent property is available. You can climb the hierarchy that way until you get to the SurfaceWindow.

HTH

Comment: keep in mind that the Parent property only walks the logical tree. If you are inside a template, you'll never reach the window using this method.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, I'd recommend you to think about your overall architecture of your application, since you're introducing a tighter coupling between your controls that is normally desirable.

That said, you can walk your apps visual tree using the [VisualTreeHelper](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.visualtreehelper.aspx)

This [stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/636383/wpf-ways-to-find-controls) has a lot of details about finding controls, and especially the [answer containing the FindVisualParent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/636383/wpf-ways-to-find-controls/636456#636456) helper method